# Why the Google Analytics API is eating the "\" in my filter query?

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am playing with Google Analytics API and found it very interesting. But today I came with a problem that can't be solved.

I am sending a filter like this:

`'filters':'ga:pagePath=~^/q-\d+/\d+$'`

It's working good in the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) but not working with my code.

After some tests I found that the query is wrong when it's sent. Here is from the "Network" panel of my Chrome debugging tool:

[image]

As in the picture, the `\d` became `d` and I guess that is the reason the data is not correctly showing up.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
var o ={
    'ids': 'ga:' + profileId,
    'start-date': $('#startdate').val(),
    'end-date': $('#enddate').val(),
    'metrics': 'ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews',
    'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
    'sort':'ga:pagePath',
    'filters':'ga:pagePath=~^/q-\d+/\d+$'
  };
gapi.client.analytics.data.ga.get(o)
.then(function(response) {
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape backslash symbols:

```
'filters':'ga:pagePath=~^/q-\\d+/\\d+$'
```

This this can be easily checked:

```
console.log('ga:pagePath=~^/q-\\d+/\\d+$');
console.log('ga:pagePath=~^/q-\d+/\d+$');
```

If you are using custom events in GA probably you can take a look at http://mixpanel.com or http://www.devmetrics.io, they provide better event model and event oriented API / UI.